# Aircrack-ng Can't Read File or Crunch's Standard Output (Fedora)

Tags: linux, fedora, aircrack-ng

Okay, so I am trying to pipe crunch to aircrack-ng, and I get the following error:

`[root@x IN /x/x]$ crunch 8 8 -t @o@@@@@@ | aircrack-ng - -b 94:0E:6B:A5:F3:32
Crunch will now generate the following amount of data: 72286291584 bytes
68937 MB
67 GB
0 TB
0 PB
Crunch will now generate the following number of lines: 8031810176 
Opening -
Unsupported file format (not a pcap or IVs file).
[root@x IN /x/x]$`
So as you can see, crunch works fine. I even tried it without the pipe, and it worked perfectly, but aircrack doesn't seem to be able to read it. I have eliminated the problem to the format of crunch's output, but still tell any other possible reasons for the error.

If I give aircrack a file to read from I get this error:

`[root@x IN /x/x]$ sudo crunch 8 8 -t @o@@@@@@ -d 5 | aircrack-ng -w - mifipass.cap -b 94:0E:6B:A5:F3:32 mifipass2
Opening mifipass.cap
read(file header) failed: Success
Crunch will now generate the following amount of data: 72286273800 bytes
68937 MB
67 GB
0 TB
0 PB
Crunch will now generate the following number of lines: 8031808200 
[root@x IN /x/x]$` This is the most I could find on the subject: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124580/what-does-read-swap-header-failed-success-mean

Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

Edit:
So, I found out part of the problem: I was using an n-dash instead of an m-dash:
`[root@x IN /x/x]$ crunch 8 8 -t @o@@@@@@ | aircrack-ng - -b 94:0E:6B:A5:F3:32`
should be:
`[root@x IN /x/x]$ crunch 8 8 -t @o@@@@@@ | aircrack-ng – -b 94:0E:6B:A5`

But now I have this error:

`[root@x IN /x/x]$ crunch 8 8 | aircrack-ng -b 94:0E:6B:A5:F3:32 -w – mifipass.cap
Crunch will now generate the following amount of data: 1879443581184 bytes
1792377 MB
1750 GB
1 TB
0 PB
Crunch will now generate the following number of lines: 208827064576 
ERROR: Opening dictionary – failed (No such file or directory)
ERROR: Opening dictionary – failed (No such file or directory)
Opening mifipass.cap
read(file header) failed: Success
[root@x IN /x/x]$` 
:F3:32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem: I wasn't using a `.cap` file. When you want to crack a wireless key with `aircrack-ng`, what you have to do is first capture enough encrypted packets (until you get a 4-way handshake) using `airodump-ng`. After you did this and saved the output to a file, you must use this file with `aircrack-ng`; as this is the file `aircrack-ng` will use to break the encryption (rather than trying the password on the actual WiFi network. Here is what to do:

```
$ airodump-ng <wireless-interface>
$ airodump-ng -c <channel> --bssid <mac:address> -w <name-for-new-file> <wireless-interface>
$ crunch <options> | aircrack-ng -w <file.cap> - --bssid <mac:address>
```

What I did here is simple:
1-A general scan of available networks. You must find your network and copy the bssid and channel.
2-Captured a 4-way handshake for my wireless network and saved it into a file without an extension
3-Used the file with the `.cap` extension with `aircrack-ng`   while telling it to read from standard output. (airodump added the extension to the file automatically)